# How to use destructor with non pointer attribute

Tags: c++, exception

I am stuck on making use of my destructor
My brief code structure is such that

```
class test
{
   private:
     string code;
     int digit, num_digit;  

   //destructor
   ~test() 
   {
      if(digit >= 0 && digit > num_digit)
      {
         for(unsigned int i=0; i<code.length(); i++) delete &code[i];
      }
   }
};

 <more code> .............
 <more code> .............

 int main()
 {
      Test test1
      test1.~test();
 }
```

My core get aborted when going through the part for destructor. Unix complier says Aborted - 'core dumped'
Any idea for it?

Comment: Why are you calling `test1.~test();` manually? You should never do that!

Comment: Also in your case your destructor is not only superfluos but causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlexChamberlain actually there is one rare exception, that is when you use placement new.

Comment: You seem to seriously misunderstand how constructors, destructors and dynamic allocation work in C++. Destructors are called *automatically* when an object's lifetime ends (local var goes out of scope, `new`ed object is `delete`d). You *must not* call them manually. And only call `delete` on something you allocated with `new`. For `std::string`, it's the job of its destructor to clean up the string. And it will do it. You might want to read a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Sure. But that's very advanced, and for a beginner, just confusing.

Comment: Totally.. Im not trying to use it thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The abort is occurring because an attempt is being made to `delete` an object that was not dynamically allocated: **only `delete` what was created via`new` (and `delete[]` for `new[]`)**. The `code` member is not dynamically allocated. It will be destroyed automatically when the containing object is destroyed. In the case of `Test` there is no reason to hand code a destructor.

This is incorrect:

```
test1.~test();
```

Don't explicitly invoke the destructor of an object. The destructor will be invoked automatically when `test1` goes out of scope. For dynamically allocated objects the destructor will be invoked when it is `delete`d.

Comment: @user2282596, internally `std::string` will have a dynmically allocated buffer but the `std::string` instance manges it itself.

Comment: Could he not just do a dummy `test1 = Test();`? This will call the destructor on test1.

Answer (score 3):

You can only delete pointers created with a call to new.

You are deleting a pointer to string which is on the stack. This gives you the core dump.